# gitlab git init gives 500 error

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

I'm a french student trying to make useable gitlab instance in my server, so far I've created the gitlab-ce website with apache2 aside.

But I keep stuck in a weird error... I've cloned a repository from github.com to my gitlab instance, no errors. But when I try to pull this repo the servers gives me a 500 Error.
I know it's certainly my gitlab instance which have a problem, so please could you gives me where should I check to resolve this bug :/

Information:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- gitlab-ce
- to access my git: http://git.axicer.fr/

Here is my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'http://git.axicer.fr'
# web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx','gitlab-www','git','www-data']
# nginx['enable'] = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a 500 error is a server-side error, you should look into /var/log/gitlab in order to see if the logs include any clue.

A simpler approach would be to declare an empty project in your GitLab instance, then clone locally a GitHub repo and push it back to that new project, as [described here](http://%20/var/log/gitlab).

Considering a Gitlab installation is generally done with the git user, you should see a Welcome message when doing a:

```
ssh -T git@git.axicer.fr
```

Comment: I've created a new repo, set the remote to my gitlab instance new repo and tried to push it, I got a 500 error as expected and I've checked in /var/log/gitlab/gitlab_rails/production.log and I got this error:
https://pastebin.com/3QEbJWgk
Can you give me somes clues ? ;)

Comment: @Axicer you seem to have an authentication issue (lack of token): https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#basic-usage. Is your repo on your GitLab instance declared as public or internal or private?

Comment: It's a public repository

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: @Axicer Did you try pushing using the ssh URL?

Comment: what should the URL be ?

Comment: @Axicer you should see the ssh URL on your project page (as in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/img/project_clone_url.png). And you need to add the public key to your GitLab profile page.

Comment: I've created a ssh key, used her in my gitlab account and used the ssh way to clone my repo but this time I get the error saying he can't find the repository :/

Comment: What url did you use?

Comment: My repository is http://git.axicer.fr/iut-info/temp so I've used the ssh key axicer@git.axicer.fr:iut-info/temp.git and added my ssh key inside my gitlab account

Comment: but it's still saying that iut-info/temp.git is not a git repository...

Comment: What does ssh -Tv axicer@git.axicer.fr return?

Comment: It asks for your password, that means the public key was not registered to your gitlab account.

Comment: I'll check that

Comment: No I've created my ssh key and used it in my account https://pastebin.com/ADC4Y10W

Comment: but I still can't push to the repository :/ it's still saying:
fatal: 'iut-info/temp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

It's still asking for my password btw :/

Comment: @Axicer Basically, `ssh -T axicer@git.axicer.fr` should give you a `Welcome to GitLab` message. As long as you don't see that, accessing the repo is pointless. Note: make sure gitlab does use the `axicer` user on that server, and not the `git` user. Follow https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html (but don't use a passphrase for your private key, for testing, so no need for ssh-agent)

Comment: Oh yes I as using axicer user instead of git... thank you very well ! :)

Comment: @Axicer No problem. I have edited the answer to better reflect that point (using account git)